# Why windres cannot find "wx/msw/wx.rc"?

Tags: wxwidgets, codelite

CodeLit 5.2, Windows 7, wxWidget 2.9.4

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile"
----------Building project:[ CL2a - Debug ]----------
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `D:/Exaos/Workspace/ms-win/CL2a'
windres -i "D:/Exaos/Workspace/ms-win/CL2a/win_resources.rc" --use-temp-file --define __WXMSW__ --define _UNICODE --include-dir C:\Apps\wxWidgets-2.9.5\lib\gcc_dll\mswu --include-dir C:\Apps\wxWidgets-2.9.5\include --define WXUSINGDLL    -o ./Debug/win_resources.rc.o
D:/Exaos/Workspace/ms-win/CL2a/win_resources.rc:1:24: fatal error: wx/msw/wx.rc: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
c:\Apps\MinGW-4.7.1\bin\windres.exe: c:\Apps\MinGW-4.7.1\bin\gcc exited with status 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Debug/win_resources.rc.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
CL2a.mk:124: recipe for target `Debug/win_resources.rc.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Exaos/Workspace/ms-win/CL2a'
Makefile:4: recipe for target `All' failed
1 errors, 0 warnings
```

I'm sure that the wx.rc is there.

Answer (score 0):

First a small correction: why can't windres find wx/msw/wx.rc

Now, at the top you wrote that you are using wx294, however winders is searching for the file under C:\Apps\wxWidgets-2.9.5 - is this path exists?

To control the search path generated by codelite you should edit the WXWIN environment variable to point to the correct wxWidgets installation folder, this can be done from:
Settings -> environment variables

(Codelite is using wx-config.exe tool to generate the flags for windres )

Eran

Comment: It's weird. The `WXWIN`, `WXCFG` are setup OK. I have to add the include path to project settings, or I will failed to compile. `windres` cannot find 'wx.rc'. But I can run the command correctly in `cmd`. It seems that CodeLite cannot accept "C:\Apps" but "C:/Apps" under Windows 7 64-bit.