# windres cannot find "wx/msw/wx.rc" building wxWidgets project with MSYS2-minGW64 and Codelite

Tags: wxwidgets, codelite, rc, windres

Opening a new questions as some [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969743/why-windres-cannot-find-wx-msw-wx-rc) does not apply to my case.

As per subject, I cannot compile a basic wxWidgets "Hello, World" program in Windows 10 with CodeLite 14 and wxWidgets 3.1.4 (compiled using MSYS2-mingW64).

The error message is at line

```
C:/Users/Federico/codelite/wxHelloWorld/win_resources.rc:1:10: fatal error: wx/msw/wx.rc: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "wx/msw/wx.rc"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The resource file flags returned by wx-config running `wx-config --rcflags` are:

```
--use-temp-file --define __WXMSW__ --define _UNICODE --include-dir C:/wx/3.1.4-msys/lib/gcc_lib/mswu --include-dir C:/wx/3.1.4-msys/include
```

All folders/files are properly in place. By tinkering with these flags I found that no errors are given, and the program is properly compile, if I *remove* the `--use-temp-file` flag, like:

```
--define __WXMSW__ --define _UNICODE --include-dir C:/wx/3.1.4-msys/lib/gcc_lib/mswu --include-dir C:/wx/3.1.4-msys/include
```

Then everything works. Unfortunately, that flag is assumed by default by wx-config, so the only easy solution to not have it would be to just stop using `wx-config` and manually configure all compiler flags. So:

- Is there any ways I could avoid this?
- What is that flag meant for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really strange because the use of `--use-temp-file` was removed from wx makefiles in the [commit 093c3067e8](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/093c3067e8ee9f1ff203bca4b7491ae22cf6853c) (Don't use windres --use-temp-file option, 2020-07-13) which is part of 3.1.4, so you shouldn't be seeing it at all.

But wait, it's even stranger, because wx-config doesn't have `--rcflags` option that you apparently use. It does have `--rescomp` option, but it has never included `--use-temp-file` in its output at all, AFAICS, and definitely not in 3.1.4.

So it looks like you're using something other than the official 3.1.4 version. And the answer to your first question is to use the official sources instead.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your answer! Here's what I found. 1) CodeLite is shipped with a pre-compiled Windows version of wx-config.exe, which is being picked as there's no others in the `PATH`, so perhaps it's based on an older source code that didn't have that fix? 2) You're right, I can run `bash wx-config.in --rescomp`, but it won't find the library's environment variables most likely because it's being run on Windows with mingW64

Comment: I'm guessing the Windows version comes from https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Wx-config_Windows_port this port, whose source code unfortunately points to a broken link

Comment: Yes, I know that there is a number of wx-config equivalents for Windows, but unfortunately they're not under our control and I have no idea what to do about them. `wx-config.in` can't be used directly, you need to run configure to generate the real `wx-config` first.